# show list of products with negative salable qty magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, multi-source-inventory, stock-availability

Is it possible to show a list of products with a negative salable qty in magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can get through by looping the product collection an checking the -ve salable qty like this.

```
        $negativeSalableQtySkus = [];
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
        /** Apply filters here */
        $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');
            $stock = $StockState->execute($sku);
            if (isset($stock[0])) {
                $qty = $stock[0]['qty'];
                if ($qty < 0) {
                    $negativeSalableQtySkus[] = $sku;
                }
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";print_r($negativeSalableQtySkus);die;
```

You can check the array *'$negativeSalableQtySkus'*, it will contain the skus of -ve salable qtys.

*Please ignore the use of ObjectManagers you can use the same by injecting dependencies in constructor*

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to implement this I am still learning. Could you point me in the right direction. @Mohd